# How to achieve rounded corner in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css

Is there any way to make the corner rounded in IE8. I have this code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HwmgQ/). It works fine in Chrome, FF, Safari and IE9+. But how it could be achieved in IE7, IE8?

Comment: It's better to just let it gracefully degrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE<9 doesn't support `border-radius`.
You can use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com) to fake it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use this: http://css3pie.com/

I haven't implemented many times it because I am lucky enough to not need to worry about that family of browsers. css3pie seems to have a solid reputation.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and IE8 doesnt work with CSS3. Try to do as old school, with images. Please read the requirements to CSS3